# python dataclass no attribute post_init

Tags: python, post, init

When I run the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class SomeClass:
    df_in: pd.DataFrame

    def __post__init__(self):
        self.b = 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df_in = pd.DataFrame([])
    p = SomeClass(df_in=df_in)
    p.b
```

I get

```
AttributeError: 'SomeClass' object has no attribute 'b'
```

Why?

EDIT:

Am I using **post__init** correctly as there is no **init** in dataclasses

Comment: Does this answer.- https://stackoverflow.com/a/55183451/6849682?

Comment: It looks to me like __post__init__ is not getting triggered and I do not know why.

Comment: It should be `__post_init__`, not `__post__init__`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `__post_init__` function is misnamed. You should only have one underscore between post and init, but you have two.

Comment: You are star. I have wasted so much time because of this.